# Разбить массив на несколько если идет прерывание при увеличение значения массива на +1

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив `$array[1,2,3,4,5,8]`

В массиве нет значения `6,7`.

Мне нужно `$array` разбить на два массива, логика разбиения если значение массива не увеличивается на `+1` предыдущего значения:

```
$array_one[1,2,3,4,5]
$array_two[8]
```

Comment: так вы алгоритм написали же. С чем возникли трудности? делаете цикл и сравниваете

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=1;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (isset($array[$key-1])) {
       if (($array[$key]-$array[$key-1]==1)) {
           $result[$i][]=$value;   
           } else {
           $i++;
           $result[$i][]=$value;
       }
    } else {
    $result[$i][]=$value;
    }
}
```

[Демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07d32f19928cacf94074d1ae59f246a06b1f435b)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Мой вариант как сделал

```
<?php
                    function GetRanges( $aNumbers ) {
                        $aNumbers = array_unique( $aNumbers );
                        sort( $aNumbers );
                        $aGroups = array();
                        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $aNumbers ); $i++ ) {
                            if( $i > 0 && ( $aNumbers[$i-1] == $aNumbers[$i] - 1 ))
                                array_push( $aGroups[count($aGroups)-1], $aNumbers[$i] );
                            else
                                array_push( $aGroups, array( $aNumbers[$i] ));
                        }
                        $aRanges = array();
                        foreach( $aGroups as $aGroup ) {
                            if( count( $aGroup ) == 1 )
                                $aRanges[] = $aGroup[0];
                            else
                                $aRanges[] = $aGroup[0] . '-' . $aGroup[count($aGroup)-1];
                        }
                        return implode( ',', $aRanges );
                    }

                    $aNumbers = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 24 );
                    echo( GetRanges( $aNumbers ));
                    ?>
```

Выводит: 1-6,10-13,20,24

Comment: Мой же вроде так же делает, только покороче :)

Comment: Да делает, но еще добавлен знак - между промежутками в разбитых массивах и между ними запятая и запихнуто в функции для быстро вызова